# Trouble understanding a problem about spectrum of a tree graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I'm having some trouble understanding a homework question. The question:

"Consider the full binary tree of depth 6. Show that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the tree, *then there is a function $f(r)$ which only depends on the depth of a vertex with eigenvalue $\lambda$*. Write an algorithm to compute numerically the second eigenvalue of the tree"

What do you think is meant by "a function $f(r)$ which only depends on the depth of a vertex with eigenvalue $\lambda$ ". I think the function is on the vertices of the graph, but what does $\lambda$ have to do with a vertex?

edit: an eigenvalue of the tree, I think is an eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix of the tree.
Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you would **define** the word "eigenvalue" as used in trees.

Comment: edited the question, I assume it means an eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix of the tree.